# Interactive View Controller dismissal and changing statusBarStyle not compatible?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit, statusbar

I'm presenting a modal `UINavigationController` with an interactive dismiss transition. The parent view controller has a dark status bar and the modal view controller a light status bar. I'm using the iOS 7 view controller-based status bar appearance configuration.

All works fine as long as I present and dismiss the view controller non-interactively. However, when I start an interactive dismiss transition and cancel it, the status bar color remains dark.

I created a [sample project](https://github.com/futuretap/UIViewController-Transitions-Example). Tap the "Menu" button, then start the interactive transition by panning from the right screen edge.

Things I've tried:

- calling `-setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` on any of the navigation and view controllers involved after the transition has been canceled
- Changing the navigationBar.barStyle to `UIBarStyleDefault` and back to `UIBarStyleBlack`

I also verified that the statusBarStyle of my modal navigation controller is set correctly:

```
(lldb) p (UIStatusBarStyle) [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentedViewController] preferredStatusBarStyle]
(UIStatusBarStyle) $8 = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
```

Still, the status bar is black.

Any further idea what I could try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me this looks like a bug ([rdar://15902745](http://openradar.appspot.com/15902745)) in `UINavigationController`. After a canceled dismissal `UINavigationController` doesn't query again its `presentedViewController` for the `preferredStatusBarStyle` but uses the `preferredStatusBarStyle` from itself. I worked around this by overwriting `-childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle`:

```
- (UIViewController*)childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle {
    if (self.presentedViewController) {
        return self.presentedViewController.childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle;
    }

    return [super childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle];
}
```

Then, to animate the change during (and not after) the dismissal, I also overwrote `-preferredStatusBarStyle`.

I pushed the workaround to the [sample project](https://github.com/futuretap/UIViewController-Transitions-Example).

Comment: Totally makes sense. However I get some sort of collision here when presentedViewController is not nil yet, but transition just finished. So essentially preferredStatusBarStyle is queried before viewDidAppear of destination controller [interactive dismiss].

Comment: According to you sample project you do a bit more work there in NVC as I assumed. https://github.com/futuretap/UIViewController-Transitions-Example/blob/master/UIViewController-Transitions-Example/FTNavigationController.m. Thank you for sample!

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to call

```
[self.transitionContext cancelInteractiveTransition];
```

within your's UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition subclasses `- (void)cancelInteractiveTransition` implementation. For inspiration, this is mine implementation

```
- (void)cancelInteractiveTransition {

id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning> transitionContext = self.transitionContext;
[transitionContext cancelInteractiveTransition];

UIView *fromView = [UIViewController fromViewForTransitioningContext:transitionContext];
UIView *toView = [UIViewController toViewForTransitioningContext:transitionContext];

if (self.presenting)
{
    CGRect endFrame = CGRectOffset([[transitionContext containerView] bounds], 0, CGRectGetHeight([[transitionContext containerView] bounds]));

    [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION_PAN animations:^{

        toView.frame = endFrame;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [transitionContext completeTransition:NO];
    }];
}
else {

    CGRect endFrame = [[transitionContext containerView] bounds];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION_PAN animations:^{
        fromView.frame = endFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:NO];
    }];
}
```

}

edit: this seems to help on iOS 8.4. Tested on 7.1 but no way. Maybe Apple fixed it lately.